# Trouble using Noyito TTL to RS232 mutual converter module

Tags: level-shifting

I need pixhawk to read a novatel gps which has rs232 output. So I purchased a noyito TTL to RS232 mutual conversion module, assuming the word mutual means it can work as rs232 to ttl converter as well.

[https://www.amazon.com/NOYITO-Module-Conversion-Arduino-communicates/dp/B07BJJC3R6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BJJC3R6)

The Novatel GPS outputs data in NMEA format, but the Pixhawk doesn't seem to recognize the GPS. When I wired it to an Arduino to see if the messages are making it through, I was unable to see anything on the serial monitor. (I connected the VCC,GND,TX,RX pins to the 5V,GND,TX,RX pins on the arduino). I'm wondering if:

1. The TTL converter I purchased is a one way converter
2. If issue has something to do with nmea data I'm passing through

Here is how I have wired it:

From the converter, I have VCC, GND, TX, RX going to the +5V,GND, TX,RX respectively on the Pixhawk. (see image below). The GPS is connected to RS232 side of the converter.

[image]

Comment: How have you wired it? It needs a 3V or 5V supply.

Comment: Please draw a schematic of how you wired it. You say "nothing showed", do you mean on a scope, or nothing appeared in software? I am from a non-mind-reader background.

Comment: Good attempt with copypasting an image from the web instead of actually showing how you connectes all the things together. We cannot possibly know without description that should TXD be connected to TXD or RXD on the TTL side. And there is a chance that the RS232 side connections are also incorrect, it is not known if you need a direct or crossover cable.